# Fail Safe Iterator giving unpredictable output

Tags: iterator, concurrenthashmap

I have an example (see code below) of a fail safe iterator using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in which two entries are added to the map while iterating.

While one of the values appears in the output, the other one does not appear in the output.

Since fail-safe works on copy of the map and not the original map should the iterator print the value added to the map while iterating?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> mp = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();  

    mp.put("one",1);
    mp.put("two",2);

    Iterator<String> itr=mp.keySet().iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)itr.next();
        System.out.println(mp.get(key));
        mp.put("three",3);
        mp.put("FIVE",5);
        System.out.println(mp);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keySet iterator is **not fail-safe**.
The behaviour you see is consistent with the published contract.

---

The [javadoc for ConcurrentHashMap#keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--) says:

> The view's iterators and spliterators are *weakly* consistent.

A visit to package-level [javadoc of the `java.util.concurrent` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) says:

> Most concurrent Collection implementations (including most Queues)
>   also differ from the usual `java.util` conventions in that their
>   Iterators and Spliterators **provide *weakly consistent* rather than
>   fast-fail traversal**:
>
> they may proceed concurrently with other operations
>   they will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`
>   they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and **may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: While using iterator for ConcurrentHashMap, does the iterator work on a copy of the map or the map itself?